# Segmentation Fault when counting elements in linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I am new to linked lists, but am trying to create a linked list with 3 elements and to write a function that counts the number of elements in said linked list.
I keep getting a segmentation fault, but I can't figure out why.
Any help would be most welcome.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {       // create a struct to build a 
    int             data;       // linked list
    struct node*    next;
};

struct node* BuildOneTwoThree() {
    struct node* head = NULL;           // pointers
    struct node* second = NULL;     // for 
    struct node* third = NULL;          // linked list

    // allocate memory on the heap for the 3 nodes
    head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    second = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    third = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    head->data = 1;     // set up 1st node
    head->next = second;

    second->data = 2;       // set up 2nd node
    second->next = third;

    third->data = 3;        // set up 3rd node
    third->next = NULL;

    return head;

}

void main(){
    int num = Length(BuildOneTwoThree);
    printf("Number of nodes:%d\n", num);

}

int Length(struct node* head) {
    struct node* current = head;    
    int count = 0;

    while(current != NULL) {
        count++;
        current = current->next;    
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Run it in a debugger and see where it is faulting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
int num = Length(BuildOneTwoThree);
```

needs to be

```
int num = Length(BuildOneTwoThree());
                                 ^^^ Missing the function call.
```

Without that, you are justing the function pointer to `Length`.

You can avoid such errors by providing declarations of functions before using them.

```
struct node* BuildOneTwoThree();
int Length(struct node* head);
```

With the functions declared at the top of the file, I get the following message from gcc:

```
soc.c: In function ‘main’:
soc.c:36:22: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘Length’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     int num = Length(BuildOneTwoThree);
                      ^
soc.c:10:5: note: expected ‘struct node *’ but argument is of type ‘struct node * (*)()’
 int Length(struct node* head);
```

---

```
typedef struct node {
    int             data;
    struct node*    next;
};
```

is not right. That produces the *useless storage class specifier in empty declaration* warning. That needs to be either

```
struct node {
    int             data;
    struct node*    next;
};
```

or

```
struct node {
    int             data;
    struct node*    next;
} node;
```

---

Also, the return type of `main` needs to be `int`,  not `void`.

Comment: When I ran it in a debugger, that was the line that was causing the seg fault. 
I am also getting a warning that I don't understand:

warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration [enabled by default]
 };
 ^

Comment: So it seems the warning the compiler gave is supposed to be if I define something, but never declare it. However I did declare 3 nodes that I had defined earlier.

So that makes me think that I have not declared any such nodes??  :/

Answer (score 2):

You need to change this line in 'main'

```
int num = Length(BuildOneTwoThree);
```

to

```
int num = Length(BuildOneTwoThree());
```

Currently your compiler should be throwing an error when you compile this file as the 'Length' function is expecting a 'struct node *' but you are passing it a function pointer.

Comment: The compiler seemed fine with it :/